# How do I perform a factory reset of my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am giving my iPhone to my daughter. How do I clear my information and set up hers? I want to make sure I do not lose any of my information from my accounts that I use on my current phone.

Answer (score 2):

Doing *Erase all Content and Settings* from **Settings / General / Reset** will do the trick.

This process will remove all settings and information from the device, letting you configure it from the very beginning, as if you had done a reinstall.

The process won't delete nor modify the iCloud's account data.

Bear in mind, then, that you should either have an [iCloud or iTunes backup](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766) or be sure that every possible information *synchronizable* with iCloud is, indeed, synchronized. To do so you should go to **Settings / iCloud** and check what's enabled and what's not.